# Is there a way to update the data by php?

Tags: php

the data  is stored in the database as the image shows. the table is `products`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCQwu.jpg

the text format data, eg:`test.txt`

```
products_model  products_price
LB2117  19.49
LB2381  25.99
LB2307  
LB2380  35.99
LB2468  10.99
LB2139  
LB2223  12.99
LB2027  15.99
LB2126  12.99
LB2308  9.99
LB2124  13.99
```

...........

now, i want to update the `products_price` with the txt file, `products_model` is unique, if the products_price in 'test.txt`is empty. using`0` to fill.

the php code:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'pwd';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('products');
$sql = 'UPDATE products
        SET products_price="..."
        WHERE products_model=...';


$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

if update one rows, i know how to do? but how to use the txt or csv file to update the price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open the file `test.txt`
- Read it line by line
- For each line read; split it on whitespace to get the product's model
  and price.
- If the price part is empty make it `0`
- Now use these values in the update query.

Translated to PHP code (without error checking):

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","r");
while($line = fgets($file)) {
  $line = trim($line);
  list($model,$price) = preg_split('/\s+/',$line);
  if(empty($price)) {
    $price = 0;
  }
  $sql = "UPDATE products
          SET products_price=$price
          WHERE products_model='$model'";    
  // run the sql query.
}
fclose($file);
```

Also you'll have to skip the first record.

Comment: i am sorry, i am not good at php, could you give me with more details, thank you.

Comment: thank you,codaddict, but when i run the code it shows an error,Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\www\update.php on line 11. the line 11 is  list($model,$price)=preg_split('/\s+/',$line); why? how to skip the first record.

Comment: what's this line  list($model,$price) = preg_split('/\s+/',$line);
 meaning? thank you.